# May I place <style> anywhere in a web page

Tags: html, css

I'm working on dynamic web pages generated with Perl. The web site mostly consists of mobile users and speed when loading pages is extremely important. Every bit/byte loaded in a page counts. I am now in the process of optimizing all web pages that is dynamically displayed with Perl.

Instead of using external style sheets I have a programmatic scheme where the CSS is displayed inline in the web pages (being generated) so that there is not a need to fetch an external .css file - this is to speed things up. With this in mind can I place `<style>` tags outside the `<head>` tag and in the `<body>` tag? This is working but I don't want to do something that is not proper practice.

The reason I want to display `<style>` tags inside the `<body>` tag is because I am only loading CSS when it is required to avoid any CSS that is not necessary. (I have a programmatic scheme on the backend to organize CSS that fits with specific pages). - Keep in mind that the pages are dynamic and generated by Perl script.

Is using CSS with `<style>` tags inside `<body>` still valid and a proper way of using CSS? I read somewhere that this is no problem with HTML5 but I can't seem to find the reference. Perhaps this will also be an issue with backward compatibility for older browsers if it is valid to use `<style>` tags in the `<body>`?

Comment: Its better practice to put <style> either inside <head></head> tag. Also you can put it in the bottom of the page.